# Change chart seris on div tag with data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm developing a graph and I need to change the attribute of a div tag. I don't have access to the whole code, so I'm stuck with using JS, no PHP (I guess I don't need that anyway).

I have the following div:

```
<div data-serie-data="[4.0,4.0,3.0,4.0,3.0]" id="chartContainer">
```

I want to replace the data-serie-data with what I retrieve from the following JS function:

```
$.getJSON('*url*', function(data) {
    document.write(data.data);
});
```

The result from this is:

```
[5.0,2.0,6.0,1.0,4.0]
```

How do I replace the current data with this result?

I've tried doing it like this:

```
$.getJSON('*url*', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("chartContainer").setAttribute("data-serie-data", data.data);
});
```

But this doesn't change the value. I've also tried setting other attributes but that does nothing aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you check if the server is answering?

Comment: Seems all answers are revolving around setting the exact same attribute as you are. What you need to do is to set the attribute and use `setData` to redraw the graph assuming this is highcharts

Comment: Yes, this is highcharts. Looking at the source the attribute isn't even set. I'm not sure what's wrong with it. EDIT: it's actually Highstock, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It does not matter: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use that, as I dont have access to the graph itself. I can only append new JS to the end of the file.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can find where it says `new Highcharts.Chart("chartContainer")` or similar and get the chart var from it.

Comment: There's a chart var, but writing the following didn't work:

highstockchart.series[0].setData(data.data,true); 

I posted a question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628369/update-data-of-existing-highstock-graph-u

If you have time to look through this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

use the following

```
 $.getJSON('*url*', function(data) {
     $('#chartContainer').attr("data-series-data", data.data);
 });
```

if data.data does not work just use data

Comment: but it works, and answers the OP original question, as the chart API was not mentioned, originally. hens why we all answered the same.

Comment: No it does not change a thing. The question already HAD set the data attribute using DOM. Nothing changes by setting it with jQUery
You need to use setData to redraw the chart

Comment: indeed now knowing the graph API the OP used, but without knowing the API, these answers all do what was asked.

Comment: They DON'T change what OP already did! You are not answering the actual question just giving a jQuery alternative to what was already tried and discarded as not having any effect!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the jQuery.attr() method.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('*url*', function(data) {
    $('#chartContainer').attr('data-serie-data', data.data)
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/0atz2tuu/)

Comment: same as  document.getElementById("chartContainer").setAttribute("data-serie-data", data.data);

Comment: Yes, mplungjan, it is.